# How to make work javascript in template in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to use js to save values in selected options. It works if js put it in my HTML template. Like this:

```
{% load static %}
{% include "header.html" %}
{% block content %}
<script src="{% static 'ReportingTool/js/sort_text.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'ReportingTool/js/sort_number.js' %}"></script>
...
                        <form method="GET" action=".">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="border border-2 p-2 g-2">
                                    <label for="periodMin">Start date</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="myselect form-select form-select-sm" id="periodMin"
                                           name="period_min">
                                    <label for="periodMax">End date</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="myselect form-select form-select-sm" id="periodMax"
                                           name="period_max">
                                </div>
                                <div class="border border-2 p-2 g-2">
                                    <label for="structDivisions">Structural divisions</label>
                                    <select id="structDivisions" class="myselect form-select form-select-sm"
                                            name="struct_division">
                                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                        {% for SD in struct_divisions %}
                                            <option id="{{ SD.id }}" value="{{ SD }}"> {{ SD }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </select>

                                    <label for="workers">Worker</label>
                                    <select id="workers" class="myselect form-select form-select-sm" name="worker">
                                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                        {% for worker in workers %}
                                            <option value="{{ worker }}">{{ worker }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="border border-2 p-2 g-2">

                                    <label for="workDone">Work done</label>
                                    <select class="myselect form-select form-select-sm" id="workDone" name="work_done">
                                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                        {% for work in workstype %}
                                            <option value="{{ work }}">{{ work }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>

                                    <label for="scope_min">Scope min</label>
                                    <input type="number" min=0 class="myselect form-control form-control-sm" id="scope_min"
                                           name="work_scope_min">

                                    <label for="scope_max">Scope max</label>
                                    <input type="number" min=0 class="myselect form-control form-control-sm" id="scope_max"
                                           name="work_scope_max">

                                    <label for="notes">Notes contains</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="myselect form-control form-control-sm" id="notes"
                                           name="work_notes_contains">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row border border-2 p-2 g-2">
                                    <button type="submit"
                                            value="sumbit"
                                            name="button_search"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100"
                                            title="Search">
                                        &#128269;
                                    </button>
                                    <button
                                            name="button_export"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100"
                                            onclick=" location.href='{% url 'export_report' %}'"
                                            title="Export csv">
                                        &#128190;
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
...

 <script>
let selItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("SelItem")) || [];

$(function() {
  if (selItems) {
    selItems.forEach(obj => {
      const [k, v] = Object.entries(obj)[0]
      $("#" + k).val(v)
    })
  }
  $('.myselect').on("change", function() {
    selItems = $('.myselect').map(function() {
      return { [this.id]: this.value }
    }).get();
      sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", JSON.stringify(selItems))



  });
});
    </script>

{% endblock content %}
{% include "footer.html" %}
```

But if I put the script in a separate file:

```
{% load static %}
{% include "header.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <script src="{% static 'ReportingTool/js/sort_text.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'ReportingTool/js/sort_number.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'ReportingTool/js/select.js' %}"></script>
```

select.js:

```
let selItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("SelItem")) || [];

$(function() {
  if (selItems) {
    selItems.forEach(obj => {
      const [k, v] = Object.entries(obj)[0]
      $("#" + k).val(v)
    })
  }
  $('.myselect').on("change", function() {
    selItems = $('.myselect').map(function() {
      return { [this.id]: this.value }
    }).get();
      sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", JSON.stringify(selItems))
  });
});
```

it doesn't work. He doesn't understand what event he reacts to? I tried to add the name of the function and call click on the event. Nothing helps
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<script src="{% static 'ReportingTool/js/select.js' %}"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="{% static '/ReportingTool/js/select.js' %}"></script> #You forgot to add forward slash(/) before ReportingTool.
```

Try and see if this is works

Comment: Nope. It still doesn't work. For example, two other scripts work without slash(/).